# Make changes to embedded linux kernel code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded

I'd like to understand & edit(adding printk, etc.) the linux kernel for a craneboard, which I obtained from [github](https://github.com/craneboard/craneboard-kernel). I'm a newbie. I have gone through certain questions related to this in stackoverflow, but they all concentrate on linux in PC (not in embedded!). I don't know where to start. Any kind of guidance is accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more detail about what's **stopping** you from making changes? Do you not know where to look, what to change, how printk works...?

Comment: @JohnU I learnt about printk in [this link](http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson5). But, I don't have any idea about where to start & where to modify, so that I understand the code.

Comment: OK, what are you hoping to change / what would you like to see or do?

Comment: @JohnU It may be anything but it must be some kind of visible modification, like I shall see a "Hello world" message.

Comment: OK, as others have said below you need to know about the kernel & compiling it... after that, find something that's printed at startup (EG "Linux version 2.6.37...") and grep the source code to find where that is printed, then insert something like "printk("Gomu says hello, world!"); on the next line. Be sure to add some comment or feature to everything you add, so you can remove it all again when you are done!

Comment: It's kinda what I'm doing, I have a TI dev board here too, and the support from TI has been, well, rubbish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear did you got chance to look at README located at

https://github.com/craneboard/craneboard-kernel

if you need to add any information or some logging i.e. adding printk in kernel itslef, you need to recompile it, it also shows how to do it. But i am interested to know why you need to put logging information in kernel? Are you going to fix some bug in kernel?

Printk is same like a C Printf, but with few differences http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3

Also have a look at http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CraneBoard

It might also be a good start to look at https://linuxlink.timesys.com/files/pdf/Timesys-EmbeddedLinuxTutorial.pdf

Comment: No, I'm just trying to understand the code. I just thought that if I could add some print statements, the code flow may be more understandable. Also, though I know that after each change, a kernel must be recompiled, my doubt is that, where do I insert that `printk`s, as I'm not aware of code flow?

Comment: I would suggest to read about building embedded linux kernel, before moving on http://www.kerneltravel.net/downloads/Building.Embedded.Linux.Systems.pdf

Comment: http://kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand002.html and  http://ceata.org/~tct/resurse/utlk.pdf are worhty of looking at

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an ARM toolchain before you can compile the kernel. [Here is a good tutorial](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-arm-and-emulate-with-qemu/).